# PHP Soap call through https

Tags: php, apache, soap, ssl, https

i have a problem with running methods with SOAP. I'm using Apache and PHP.

this is the PHP code:

```
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'RC4-SHA')
);

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

$client = new SoapClient('https://host?wsdl', array (
'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
"trace" => 1,
"exceptions" => 0,
"connection_timeout"=>2000));
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

$params = array ("key" => "value");
$result = $client->availabeFunction($params);
var_dump($result);
```

The `__getFunctions()` It returns me all of the available functions.

Then when i'm trying to call the the available function with parameters.

It returns me a strage error message:

```
public 'faultstring' => string 'Could not connect to host' (length=25)
public 'faultcode' => string 'HTTP' (length=4)
```

So i presume it is for some reasons are connecting to through the HTTP, but not through HTTPS.

I've looked up the web, and in some cases they are using a `local_cert` value with a .pem file.

It it neccecity to have it? Or i'm missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

It's an openssl library bug.

At first try to disable SSL check by adding this params

```
"stream_context" => stream_context_create(
    array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer'       => false,
            'verify_peer_name'  => false,
        )
    )
)
```

And next try to not use **?wsdl** in location link, try use something like 
**.wsdl**

Comment: Can confirm this works in my case, where the same script works fine in 5.4 and 5.5, I just need to add the `'verify_peer_name' => false` in addition of `verify_peer` for 5.6 to work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was much easier as i thoguht it will be:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

$location = 'https://host';

$client = new SoapClient($location . '?wsdl', array (
"trace" => 1,
"exceptions" => 0,
"connection_timeout"=>2000,
"location"=>$location // <- this was the reqiured parameter
));
```

Everything else is same as before.
This beeing cause by WSDL file configuration, that instead of https URL, it has http.

Comment: While this "works," you absolutely **DO NOT** want to do it this way. Why? Because the `https://` wrapper disables peer certificate verification by default prior to PHP 5.6. By eliminating the ssl context you've basically said, *"I don't care who is on the other end of this transfer, I trust them completely".* If you're dealing with data you don't want me to be able to read or modify this is not the correct solution.